# Error: (namespace.Activity) does not implement interface member"android.views.view.,Ontouch"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, implementation, ontouchlistener

I am using xamarin(c#) to build a andriod application. I would like to do drag and drop function of a button. I used ontouch listener and follow the guildence of official website but it doesnt work.([the official guidelines:detech a touch](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/))

It continues to have a error that CountUpDown.LearnMaths(namespace.Activity) does not implement interface member"andriod.views.ontouchlisterner"

CountUpDown.axml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#DEDEDC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img04"
        android:id="@+id/dragObj"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CountUpDown.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


namespace LearnMaths
{


    [Activity (Label = "CountUpDown")]          
    public class CountUpDown : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
    {

        private Button dragObj;
        private float _viewX;



        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.CountUpDown);

            dragObj = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.dragObj);
            dragObj.SetOnTouchListener (this );
            // Create your application here
        }

        public bool onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
            switch (e.Action) 
            {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                _viewX= e.GetX ();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                var right = (int)(left + v.Width);
                v.Layout (left, v.Top, right, v.Bottom);
                break;  

            }
            return true;

    }
    }

}

    enter code here
```

Comment: View.IOnTouchListener =>View.OnTouchListener Or public class CountUpDown : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener is wrong?I don't really know xamarin.

Comment: its c# xamarin just like andriod studio but  using c#

Comment: In android, public class CountUpDown extend Activity implement View.IOnTouchListener.Activity and View.IOnTouchListener can't be sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization matters:

```
public bool onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
```

should be (capital "O")

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
```